# Workflow in sharepoint 2010 code

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow-activity, designer-workflow

I'm new in sharepoint user 2010,so i wanna ask the question about workflow in sharepoint. My supervisor asked me to do sharepoint programming in development server with copy down all the codes and do the exact the same workflow from the production server. The problem is,when I copy down all the workflow from production site to development site, it did not gave the same result from production site. My question is how can I trace the error from my workflow or anything that i'm doing wrong with my workflow from development to production.

thank you.if you did not understand my question just email me luq.hakim14@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

what exactly you mean by Code ? by copy you mean deploying WSP (SharePoint Package) file ? if you are not logging exception in Workflow history list then you should find thrown exception in ULS log at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\ try using [UlsViewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) utility for viewing log.

Comment: thank you for your help i'll try to do what you have suggest,yeah I mean deploying WSP not code